# What does 되다 mean exactly in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, meaning

I'm looking for the exact definition of 되다 in this sentence. 
Can anyone tell me which definition of 되다 here from [this krdict dictionary](https://krdict.korean.go.kr/eng/dicSearch/search?nation=eng&nationCode=6&ParaWordNo=&mainSearchWord=%EB%90%98%EB%8B%A4)?

> 그곳은 우리 집에서 조금만 걸으면 됩니다

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to Definition 19! The meaning is "To be all right or no problem".
If you are confused, you may see the sentence structure.
19th meaning needs the structure, "1이 2-면 되다", like the examples there. 
ex) 가만히 있으면 되다 / 가면 되다
ex) 조금만 기다리면 돼.